# Update table using custom queries in TYPO3 Extbase

Tags: php, mysql, typo3, extbase

I have a table named 'user'.I need to update the field 'email'  .Is there any custom build queries for updating.I have only the uid of user.

I mean.. Is there any TYPO3 custom queries equivalent to

> Update table 'user' set email = 'new@xyz.com' where uid = 1;

like

> $query = $this->createQuery();
>       $query->matching(
>           $query->logicalAnd(
>               $query->equals('organization', $organization),
>               $query->contains('regions', $region)
>           )
>       )
>       return $query->execute();

Comment: Is this like, you want to update a record say whose uid is fetched with findByUid() ???  Then better you use setter function for the corresponding field.

Comment: After setting the field with a setter, simply invoke update too. You got what I meant, right ??

Comment: @AnuBhuvanendranNair You are right...

Comment: No problem. Keep up your quick response.That'll be helpful for other solution seekers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why don't you use

```
use HDNET\ExtensionName\Utility;

Utility::exec_UPDATEquery   (
    $table,
    $where,
    $fields_values,
    $no_quote_fields = false 
);
```

Please refer [exec_UPDATEquery From TYPO3](https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_dbal_1_1_database_1_1_database_connection.html#a573e8a4a77fa3684e6a0b867e42a996c)

Answer (score 2):

if you use extbase , you can use :

```
$object = $this->yourRepository->yourQuery();
$object->setEmail('your@email.tld');
$this->yourRepository->update($object);
```